# Как остановить кэширование controller.js в Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте. Как отключить кэширование файла controller.js в Angular?

Answer (score 1):

Angular не умеет кешировать JS код, его кеширует браузер. В Chrome и подобных браузерах кеширование легко отключить открыв `Инструменты разработчика (F12)` и открыть `Settings (F1)` и выбрать опцию `Disable cache (while DevTools is open)`. Кеш файлов будет автоматически сбрасывать при перезагрузке страницы.